# Why does `factor` return `NA` for my data?

Tags: r, forcats

I want to use R package `forcats` to turn my data from character to factor.My data was stored as strings in a "xlsx." file. I wonder why it turns to NA?

Here is the screenshot on my computer when I run the code.

[image]

```
library("tidyverse")
library(readxl)
library(forcats)
conjoint_analysis <- read_excel("OneDrive/\u9879\u76ee/\u8054\u5408\u5206\u6790（\u822a\u5609\u6167\u5e08\u59d0）/conjoint_analysis.xlsx")
a <- c('male','female','male','male','female')
print(factor(a))
print(conjoint_analysis[,3])
print(factor(conjoint_analysis[,3]))
```

Comment: Try `conjoint_analysis$Gender <- factor(conjoint_analysis$Gender)`

Comment: Thank you!!! It works. Could you tell me why could that work?